# React calling dynamic state names

Tags: reactjs, loops, error-handling, state, jsx

I have a loop where I go trough in JSX `for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfChilderen; i++)` . For every child I add an element to the form. But for error control I also have an array containing all the error messages. Every individual error message gets a different key. So the first child in the list will get 'birthday0' as key for if there is an error with the entered birthday. So now I want to check if every child has a specific error.

The problem is that I can't get the state variable to be dynamic `this.state.errorMessage.birthday+ [i]`. Here is an example of an element inside the loop:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
            value={this.state.childeren[i].birthday}
              variant="inline"
              format="dd/MM/yyyy"
              margin="normal"
              id={"birthday" + i}
              onChange={(e, value) => this.dateChangedHandler(e, value, i)}
              label="Geboortedatum"
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change date",
              }}

            helperText={
              this.state.errorMessage.birthday+ [i] && this.state.errorMessage.birthday+ [i]
            }
            error={!!this.state.errorMessage.birthday+ [i]}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
error={!!this.state.errorMessage[`birthday${i}`]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to access a property with key `birthday + [i]` as a string, the problem with your code as that the engine understands it like this

```
!!this.state.errorMessage.birthday + [i] means evaluate expression (!!this.state.errorMessage.birthday) which is a boolean and then add it to expression [i] which is array, which i doubt to be what you want

instead you want the following, which means access property birthday + [i] as a string of the object this.state.errorMessage
error={!!this.state.errorMessage.[`birthday${i}`]}
```